# How to write boto3 response to CSV?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, boto3

New to Python/Boto3 so this is a little confusing.  I am trying to get AWS Security Hub findings written to a csv using csv.writer but only certain items in the response.  I can get the correct columns and rows written to csv however when I try to loop through the writer it just repeats the same row, not the other data from the response. I feel like I'm overlooking something simple, any help is appreciated.

```
def getSecurityHubFindings():
  hub = boto3.client('securityhub')
  findingsList = []
  for key in paginate(hub.get_findings, Filters=filters, PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': MAX_ITEMS}):
    scantype = key['Types']
    str1 = ''.join(scantype)
    port=key['ProductFields']['attributes:2/value']
    vgw=key['ProductFields']['attributes:3/value']
    scantype = key['Types']
    str1 = ''.join(scantype)
    findingAccountId = key['AwsAccountId']
    findingLastObservedAt=key['LastObservedAt']
    findingFirstObservedAt=key['FirstObservedAt']
    findingCreatedAt=key['CreatedAt']
    findingrecommendation=key['Remediation']['Recommendation']
    findingTypes=key['Types']
    InstanceId=key['Resources'][0]['Id']
    findingInstanceId=str(InstanceId)
    findingAppCode=key['Resources'][0]['Tags']['AppCode']
    findingGeneratorId=key['GeneratorId']
    findingProductArn=key['ProductArn']
    findingTitle=key['Title']
    findingsList.append(key)

    if (str1 == 'Software and Configuration Checks/AWS Security Best Practices/Network Reachability - Recognized port reachable from a Peered VPC'):
      vgw=''
      port=key['ProductFields'][ 'attributes:4/value']
      peeredvpc= key['ProductFields']['attributes:2/value']

    if (str1 == 'Software and Configuration Checks/AWS Security Best Practices/Network Reachability - Recognized port reachable from a Virtual Private Gateway'):
      peeredvpc=''
      sev = key['Severity']['Product']
      if (sev == 3):
        findingSeverity='LOW'
      elif (sev == 6):
        findingSeverity='MEDIUM'
      elif ( sev == 9):
        findingSeverity='HIGH'

    rows = [findingAccountId, findingGeneratorId, findingTitle,findingProductArn,findingSeverity,findingAppCode,findingFirstObservedAt,findingLastObservedAt,findingCreatedAt,findingrecommendation,findingTypes,port,vgw,peeredvpc,findingInstanceId]

    columns = ('Account ID', 'Generator ID', 'Title', 'Product ARN', 'Severity', 'AppCode', 'First Observed At','Last Observed At', 'Created At', 'Recommendation', 'Types', 'Port', 'VGW', 'Peered VPC', 'Instance #ID')

    with open(FILE_NAME, mode='w', newline='',) as writefile:
      writefile_writer = csv.writer(writefile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
      writefile_writer.writerow(columns)
      i = 0
      while i < MAX_ITEMS:
        writefile_writer.writerow(rows)
        i +=1

  return(findingsList)
```

Comment: You are opening the CSV file for every row, and you are using `w` mode so the file is being erased each time. Open the file, then within your context manager, iterate over the security results and write them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

The general flow should be:

```py
def getSecurityHubFindings():
    ...

    # Open output file and write header
    columns = ('Account ID', 'Generator ID', 'Title', 'Product ARN', 'Severity', 'AppCode', 'First Observed At','Last Observed At', 'Created At', 'Recommendation', 'Types', 'Port', 'VGW', 'Peered VPC', 'Instance #ID')

    with open(FILE_NAME, mode='w', newline='',) as writefile:
      writefile_writer = csv.writer(writefile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
      writefile_writer.writerow(columns)

      ## Loop through response
      for key in paginate(...):

          ...
          (get data here)
          ...

          # Write output
          row = [findingAccountId, findingGeneratorId, findingTitle,findingProductArn,findingSeverity,findingAppCode,findingFirstObservedAt,findingLastObservedAt,findingCreatedAt,findingrecommendation,findingTypes,port,vgw,peeredvpc,findingInstanceId]
          writefile_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your file within the for loop every time with the 'w' option which truncates the file [[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and writes from the beginning, so you're overwriting your csv each time.

The block

```
      while i < MAX_ITEMS:
        writefile_writer.writerow(rows)
        i +=1
```

also seem wrong, this just writes the same row (even though its called rows) MAX_ITEMS number of times.  You probably want to open your csv file and write the header names outside of the `for` loop, and then write a single row for each iteration of the `for` loop.